# how to turn a list of strings into an object?

Tags: python, class, object, for-loop

It's literally my second day on python so if this involve complex stuff like metaclasses just tell me, so I can come back to it when I'll be more experienced.
I'm trying to convert strings in objects and I think I almost got it, everything is detailed in the code section.

```
mike carpenter miami
jon driver roma
erika student london

# here's my text file, is a list of strings
```

```py
p = []

with open('people.txt', 'r') as text:
    for line in text:
        values = line.split(' ')
        p.append((values[0], values[1], values[2]))

#this converts each string in the text file in a list of strings with
# substrings becoming strings, all is put in a tuple named p

class person:
    def __init__(self, name, job, location):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.location = location

#this is my class, pretty self-explanatory
#now I can create objects like this:

person_number_0 = person(p[0][0], p[0][1], p[0][2])

#I can create objects using the tuple, but I don't want to do it manually
#for every different index, so I was thinking about a for-loop

n = 0
for line in p:
    obj = person(p[n][0], p[n][1], p[n][2])
    n = n + 1
#but I don't know how to create a new obj's name for every index
```

Also if I run

```
print(obj.name)
```

it gives me Mike, shouldn't it be Erika because at the end of the for-loop

```
obj = person(p[2][0], p[2][1], p[2][2])
```

or is not?

If it is something too complicated I'll back off, don't destroy me pls. Thanks everybody for any help or lessons.

Comment: The only complicated part is trying to understand what you are trying to get done.

Comment: Perhaps you want to create a list of people rather than making `obj` point to different people in turn? Something as simple as `people = [person(*line.split()) for line in list_of_strings]` should work.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a list of strings in a object so: `p[0]` becomes `person_number_0 = person(p[0][0], p[0][1], p[0][2])`

Comment: I already created a list of people is `p =[ ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Code:

```
# ignore this part it is the same as your code to read from the file
persons = [x.split() for x in """
    mike carpenter miami
    jon driver roma
    erika student london
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]


class Person:
    # this converts each string in the text file in a list of strings with
    # substrings becoming strings, all is put in a tuple named p
    def __init__(self, name, job, location):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.location = location

    def __str__(self):
        # this allows showing the class as a string (str)
        return "name: {}  job: {}  loc: {}".format(
            self.name, self.job, self.location)


for p in persons:
    print(Person(p[0], p[1], p[2]))
```

#### Results:

```
name: mike  job: carpenter  loc: miami
name: jon  job: driver  loc: roma
name: erika  job: student  loc: london
```

Answer (score 2):

Having defined your class as you have, then simply read the file as something like:

```
with open('people.txt', 'r') as f:
    people = [person(*line.split()) for line in f]
```

Now you could see the contents as:

```
for p in people:
    print(p.name, p.job, p.location)
```

Comment: Good answer (+1), but perhaps using `with` would be a tad more accurate.

Comment: @JohnColeman That's a fair point, I was just being nastily concise.

Comment: It looks like OP could benefit from such concision. New Python programmers almost always write too much code.

Comment: maybe I'm missing smthing because it's 2.30 am here but how can I print out a single word? For example "driver"?

Comment: @Skalfaro `print("driver")`

Comment: *what if I want to print the job of the second person of then list?